# Icons in Ubuntu 11.04 + Unity are wrong

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 Desktop (32-bit) in a virtual box instance. I have the VM running with the new Unity desktop and it working fine except the icon set and the toolbar are showing up as the default GNOME matte gray interface.

What the heck is going on?

How do I get sleek black Ubuntu theme and Icons back?

Comment: New 12.04 LTS is out

Comment: Yeah I am currently using it. This question is pushing a year old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Ubuntu icon theme is Unity-icon-theme.

You can switch back to using the default theme using Ubuntu tweak. You can follow the instructions provided on Ask Ubuntu to install Ubuntu tweak.

- [How do I install Ubuntu tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

Move to Tweaks → Theme and change the *Icon theme* to `unity-icon-theme`.

[image]

**Note:** The screenshot provided may not resemble how Ubuntu tweak appears in 11.04.